# MVC how to add two fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to multiply two fields that are in my view.

View

```
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ship_Quantity)
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Deal_Amt_1)
  <p>Output Total Here</p>
```

I want to multiply these two fields to get a total amount
and show it, in the view.  How to do it?  Can I do it directly in the view or
do I have to modify the model?  I am using .edmx models created, so I do not
want to modify them directly.

Comment: If you want the sum of the 2 fields to appear simultaneously, you'll have to write some Javascript.

Comment: You are giving  values to `Ship_Quantity` and `Deal_Amt_1` from Htppget controller or the user is entering values in these fields????

Comment: they are being populated from controller

Comment: then use `<p>@(Model.Ship_Quantity * Model.Deal_Amt_1)</p>`

Comment: gives error.  I think because you using Model?

Comment: make sure that your setting some values in `Ship_Quantity` and `Deal_Amt_1` from controller action.

Comment: "gives error" - the only worse description would be a forged error message. Please provide the error message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var shipquantity = item.Ship_Quantity;
var dealamt1 = item.Deal_Amt_1;
var TotalAmountLine2 = shipquantity * dealamt1;

output: @TotalAmountLine2
```

Comment: If you can format it properly into razor syntax this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, It will Work

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Ship_Quantity * Model.Deal_Amt_1)
```

Comment: Have you used @Html.Raw ?

Comment: I tried with @() but it was not working, When i tried it with @Html.Raw() it worked

Comment: I know, it should have worked with @(), but unfortunately its not. I don't know whats the matter.

Comment: @PratikBhoir...there must be problem somewhere else...but as per OP's qiestion there is no need of `@Html.Raw()`.